# OS X Terminal: A way to print to a file the last-modified time of each file in a folder?

Tags: macos, terminal

I render complex fractal animations, and the renderer places each frame into a folder (with names image00000.png, image00001.png, image00002.png, and so on.) I need to monitor how fast the frames are being created, and going through each image and looking at how many are being created per minute is highly tedious. Is there a way to print the last modified time of each image in this folder to a text file using Terminal (or by any means?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will list the files in reverse-modified-time-order:

```
$ ls -lrt *
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly with `$ ls -lrt * > ../modfied.txt`.